# How to do deep copy by overloaded assignment operator of subclass of std::vector<T>?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

I have a class `Step` derived from `std::vector<unsigned int>`. I need to overload assignment operator because of the deep copy used in assignment of a value returned from a static method. I can't figur out how should I copy all elements of `rhv` to `this` in assignment:

```
class Step : public std::vector<unsigned int>
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outStream, const Step& step);
    Step& operator =(const Step& rhv);
    static Step fromString(const std::string &input);
    // Something like: Step x = Step::fromString("12 13 14 15 16");
private:
    double time;
    double pause;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
};
```

and then overloading `=`:

```
Step& Step::operator =(const Step& rhv)
{
    time = rhv.time;
    pause = rhv.pause;
    id = rhv.id;
    // How should I copy contents of rhv to `this` safely?
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid deriving from standard library containers. They aren't designed for it, and you have to be *very* careful to do it safely. Why would you want to inherit from `std::vector` anyway?

Comment: Why exatly do you need to overload the assignment operator? Since you are not doing any manual resourcemanagement the compiler generated one should work fine the way I see it (as least for the code you have shown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure from your question, but I think you are asking about calling the parent `operator=`. In that case you have two options:

```
std::vector<unsigned int>::operator=(rhv); //either explicitly call the parent assignment op
*static_cast<std::vector<unsigned int>*>(this) = rhv; //or cast this to parentclass and call assignment on that
```

Of course in the code you have shown us you don't do any manual resource handling, so I don't see why you want to write your own assignment operator, the compiler generated one should do fine. Besides if you write your own assignment operator you might want to head the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) and write your own copy constructor and destructor too (at least in C++03, C++11 can be a bit different due to movable but not copyable classes).

As another sidenote: Most standardlibrary classes are not designed to be derived from, so you might want to rethink your design requiering you to inherit form `std::vector`

Comment: Subjective, but `static_cast<std::vector<unsigned int>&>(*this)` is more readable to me.

Comment: `this->assign(rhv.begin(),rhv.end())` works too. but I'll use `static_cast<std::vector<unsigned int>&>(*this)`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inheriting from standard containers is generally considered a bad idea because they aren't designed to be used as base classes (no virtual destructor among other things). Composition is preferred in pretty much every case.

Assuming you've decided to step into this minefield, you can invoke the parent assignment operator with a `static_cast`.

`*static_cast<std::vector<unsigned int>*>(this) = rhv;`

and don't forget to assign `name` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you really don't have to overload `operator=` because the default generated one will work just fine (by assigning each member and base class in turn).

If you define your own operator, you can call the base class operator, just like you would call another base class function

```
std::vector<unsigned int>::operator=(rhv);
```

and let the vector handle its own assignment.